# What are theese types of pushbuttons?

Tags: button

The controls of my alarm clock seems to not respond and I thought that pushbutton springs may have stopped working. Hence I crack oppened it in order to replace them with some spare pushbuttons I had.

Once I oppened them I found out that the design of the pushbuttons are the following:

[image: The pushbutton desighn]

So How I can replace them? These are not in the familiar design of the push button:

[image: Normal push button image]

What I see are a metal plate covered by tape and I understand that there's some sort of spring underneath. Once I pull the tape the metalic cap peels off. Do you have any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are called triangular tactile metal dome pushbuttons.

When you push it, it makes an electrical contact between two pads on the PCB, otherwise there should be no contact between the two pads.

You can use a multimeter in resistance or beep mode to test if they bridge the contact properly or not.

Comment: And a contact cleaner spray can often fix them.

Comment: Would rubbing alcohol will suffice as well?

Comment: I'd say they are mostly similar. I routinely clean with anything that has isopropanol in it.